# Is this password-less auth flow secure?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, password-less

I'd like to implement a passwordless auth flow for my mobile app that only requires a user clicking a link in their email to log in. Similar to how Slack handles auth. I'll be using `node` and `jwt` for this implementation.

I think I've come up with a secure design, but I'm sure I'm missing something. I would love some critique from the community .

Here we go:

- User opens the mobile app.
- We check to see if user has a token in their local storage.
- If they do, we add that token to their headers and send to the home page of the app.
- Else, we prompt them to enter their email to get started
- When they click "Submit", we POST that `email address` to the `requestMagicLink` endpoint on our server.
- The server checks the database for a user with that `email address`
- If we find a user with that email, we take the `id` from that user
- If the user does not exist, we create a new user, and get that `id`
- We use JWT to generate a token with the `id`, and our `secret` that expires after `1 hour`
- We send that token to the user via a link in an email.
- Upon being clicked, that link sends a GET request to our server at the `magicLogin` endpoint with the `token` in a query param
- We verify that the token is correct using JWT and our `secret`.
- If it fails verification, we redirect the user to the screen where we prompt them with their email to get started.
- If it's successful, we generate a new JWT token using their `id`, and our `secret` that `doesn't have an expiration`, then pass that back to the user in the params of a URL that redirects them to a success page in our app.
- The app takes the token from the param and stores it in local storage until the user chooses to logout, and the user is redirected to the home page.
- The requests to the api all now contain the token in the headers, and the user is good to go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah, good point! Posting it there and closing this. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197894/is-this-password-less-auth-flow-secure

Comment: for what it's worth, the only issue i'm seeing here is the the no-expiration secret is sent in a url. that's bad. (send it as a POST parameter instead) - but i just quickly skimmed your post.